# I there a way to customize a shortcut to "show macrovariable value" in the SAS log

Tags: sas, shortcut

I work with a lot of different SAS-program, coded by a handful of different people. Sometimes its difficult to remember the values of a given macro-variable, I usually type;

```
rsubmit;
 %put &Macroname. ; 
endrsubmit;
```

(I have rsubmit; defined a shortcut)
But this - accumulated takes a substantial amount of time.

Is it possible to create a user defined shortcut, which, when a word is
selected, will write the macro-variable value in the log.

So is it possible to define a shortcut (ex. F6) that will execute;

```
rsubmit; %put &TTTT.;
```

of whatever selected word, TTTT ?

Comment: Which client are you using ? Display manager session (DMS), EG, Studio ? Unfortunately, the DMS environment does not have an automatic macro variable, nor a simple reflection infrastructure, that allows you to access the selected text in either the Enhanced Editor or the Program Editor.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for, but depending on the number of macro variables you have, `%put _global_;` or `%put _local_;` may be useful.

Comment: To see what value a macro variable has just use `%put &=mvar;`.  It looks like you are asking how to see the value of a macro variable defined in a remote session created using SAS/Connect.  Are you asking for help defining a macro you can use that will generate code to show the value of a macro variable in that remote session for you?

Comment: @Richard, I'm using sas 9.4 TS level 1M5  (hope this is enough? info)

Comment: @J_Lard, I usually use  `%put _user_;`, and by further pondering I could just use this in a shortcut..
edit, fixed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DMS you can setup a function key definition by issuing the `KEYS` command.

A key definition issues one or more commands, and the command `GSUBMIT` will submit code for you!

So this definition should display the remote sessions user macro variables

```
Ctrl-T       gsubmit 'rsubmit; %put _user_;'
```

Where as this definition will display the user macro variables of the current session.

```
Ctrl-U       %put _user_
```

If you don't have a remote connection, try out this definition for `gsubmit` demonstration

```
Ctrl-W       gsubmit 'proc print data=sashelp.class; run;'
```

Comment: I have chosen this as the answer, since it gives an easy solution to my problem, even though it isn't possible to get printet one selected text as macro variable. (sadly).

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said in the comments above, to print any macro variable you can simply use `%put &=mvar;`.

> Is it possible to create a user defined shortcut, which, when a word is selected, will write the macro-variable value in the log.
>   So is it possible to define a shortcut (ex. F6) that will execute?.

No, but you can define macro to generate code `%put &=mvar;` for your program using hotkeys and simlpy put the var name to be displayed instead of "mvar".(Program->Editor Macros->Macros->Create if u work with Guide)

More info [here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2018/02/16/efficiency-at-your-fingertips-keyboard-macros-and-function-keys/).

Comment: Yes, this is probably the way I should go.
But I will have to copy/write the text, instead of =mvar, and either have an empty document open, or write and erase the code.

Thx for the help.

Comment: No need for a new editor window. Just use the command line to type the %put command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SAS Display Manager then just type the %PUT command on the command line.

[image]
[image]

Or use gsubmit command to submit non macro code.

Comment: This just need the gsubmit, as rsubmit, as posted from Richard, thansk :)